# Component isn't hiding with CSS (React.JS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So for an app, I decided to show an equation (for an app), and have real-time value updates for each value (with a button to show/hide the equation at will). So for that, not only do I have an equation component in the main app component (App.js), I also decided to put the equation component in the same file as my values component (value.js), in order to access the values and pass them as props to the equation component. I figured that I could hide the equation component in the value component, so only the equation component in the main app component is showing, and so I can also access the props at the same time, so I typed in something like this:

```
<Equation 
className="hide"
FLoad={this.state.FLoad}
DLoad={this.state.DLoad}
DLowerBack={this.state.DLowerBack}
FTorso={this.state.FTorso}
DTorso={this.state.DTorso}
FLowerBack={this.state.FLowerBack}/>
```

and the "hide" class looks something like:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

However, when I run my app, both show up simultaneously, and the two equations overlap each other. Why is that? Why doesn't the equation in the values component hide, even with the proper CSS tags? I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's some more code for some more context

```
render() {
        return(
            <div className="Equation">Force of Lower Back () = (-1 x (Force Load  x ( Distance Load / Distance Lower Back)) + (-1 x Force Torso x (Distance Torso / Distance Lower Back))
            <div>Upward Force From Legs () = Force Load + Force Torso + Force Lower Back</div></div>

        );
    }
}
```

^The code in the equation component

EDIT #2:

```
{equation ? <div>
        <Equation/> 
        <button className="EquationButton" onClick = {() => equationVisibility(!equation)}>Hide Equation</button>
      </div> :
      <button className="EquationButton" onClick = {() => equationVisibility(!equation)}>Show Equation</button>}
      <Input />
    </div>
```

^Here's the code in the main app component as well. (The Input component being the values component I was talking about earlier)

Comment: Can you post the equation component? perhaps add more code so we can see where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Check the new edit that I made.

Comment: In your `<div className="Equation">`, do ```<div className={`Equation ${this.props.className}`} />```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, the `className="hide"` is not working on your `Equation` component. It can be due to this `Equation` not using it internally. You should receive the className in the `Equation` and apply it manually to the internal component that needs to be hidden.

```
const Equation = ({ className }) => (
  <div className={className} />
)
```

However, I would recommend you to create a prop to hide it or not, this way:

```
const Equation = ({ hide }) => {
  if (hide) {
    return null
  }

  return <div>{...}</div>
}
```

So you can use it this way:

```
<Equation 
  hide
  // other props
/>
```

EDIT:

Based on the new piece of code that you showed, you can do this:

```
render() {
    return(
      <div className={`Equation ${this.props.className}`}> // <--- add this
        Force of Lower Back () = (-1 x (Force Load  x ( Distance Load / Distance Lower Back)) + (-1 x Force Torso x (Distance Torso / Distance Lower Back))
        <div>
          Upward Force From Legs () = Force Load + Force Torso + Force Lower Back
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Nah, I'm still getting the same thing. :/

Answer (score 1):

When you use a custom component like that you need to pass the appropriate props. Maybe you should add a `className` prop to the component and then add the following line:

```
<element className={className} />
```

You can use the `...` spread operator to add all of the properties:

```
const Equation = ({...props}) => {
    return (
        <element {...props} />
    )
}
```